# Dosen't work hover over element and click (python selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, seleniumbase

I'm running into an issue with my Selenium script on Python.

Here is the code I am currently working with. The test opens the page and did nothing: there is no hover and click.
I'm new with Python and with programming in general, I can't figure out how to sequence this correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Python 3.9.0
selenium==3.141.0
seleniumbase==1.50.14

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class NavigationTest(BaseCase):

    def setup_class(self):
        self.base_url = "https://www.babyshop.com/"

    def test_basket(self):
        # go to the goods page
        self.get(self.base_url + 'edushape/s/2003')
        # hover and click on the 1st position
        self.hover_and_click('//article[1]', '//article[1]//div[@class="quickshop-btn__holder"]',
                             By.XPATH, By.XPATH)
        self.sleep(3)
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933914/selenium-python-hover-and-click-on-element

Comment: Try using the Action Chains function https://stackoverflow.com/a/19945634/14388939