# How can I interact with this page? Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use python, along with selenium with beautifulsoup, to pull data/interact with a web app. I am able to connect and pull data for one item fine. The problem I am having is that the web app uses a 'tab' system to open pages within the same window. So for example in one window/one browser tab there could be five different app tabs open with similarly formatted HTML but different data. I want to be able to close these tabs as I work with the same selenium driver. I have narrowed the element down to where I'd click to do this in the HTML.

It looks like this

`<div class="close" data-ember-action="21">`

However, I can't seem to interact with the page how I'd like.

to try to click this element I have

```
item.click() #where item is  <div class="close" data-ember-action="21">
```

The HTML code looks like this

```
<div class="tab-content-holder">
  <div class="close" data-ember-action="21">×</div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```

The error message is

*line 171, in closeIt
    item.click()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable*

I have also tried something like this from another post([How to mouseover in python Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092748/how-to-mouseover-in-python-webdriver) ) without much luck.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("close")
hov = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element)
hov.perform() #what's this?
driver.find_element_by_class_name("close").click()
```

There's actually no error message. The program just stalls when it gets to the click() function.

Is there something simple I'm missing/any alternative way I should be working on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is unclear... What I gathered from your question is that you want to close the popup window that is opened by clicking on a tab.

According to my knowledge, tabs can be clicked using class names and text obtained by those class names.

In the above html if you want to click on "X" use the below code:

```
options = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("close")
for i in options:
    if i.text == "X":
       i.click()
```

Comment: This worked for me. 

My mistake was I was trying using beautifulsoup's find_all to get a clickable item.

By tabs I meant the web app has tabs embedded in the page.

Thanks a lot!