# Selenium Python document.getElementsByClassName()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I'm using Selenium with Python3 to automate entering data into a website.
I have tried looking everywhere for how to deal with selecting an element by class if there is more than one but I can't figure out how to select the accordion-toggle[1]. Nothing happens on selenium but it works fine on any browser. Also, is there any way to just use the regular javascript or jquery commands?:

```
accordion=find_element_by_class("accordion-toggle"[1])
accordion.click()
#otheraccordion=find_element_by_css_selector("#AdvancedAddress > div.accordion-heading.in > div.accordion-toggle > span.accordionExpandCollapse")
#otheraccordion.click()
StreetNameField=driver.find_element_by_id("Advanced_FindMyParcel_PropertyStreetName")
StreetNameField.send_keys("Sherman")
ZipField=driver.find_element_by_id("Advanced_FindMyParcel_PropertyZip")
ZipField.send_keys("90201")
ZipButton=driver.find_element_by_id("btnSearchFindMyParcels")
ZipButton.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `find_element(s)_by_css_selector` - [reference here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/locating-elements.html) - use the css prefix '.classname` to indicate the class.

e.g. to find

```
<div class='theClass'>

driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.theClass')
```

You can also use the `By` syntax:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.theClass')
```

**Edit**
It seems the problem may be more to `Clicking` the element, rather than finding it.

- Ensure the element is visible
- For Chrome, you may need to mimic hovering the mouse over the element before clicking this - see [Actions / ActionChains MoveToElement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11092748/314291) to hover over the element.
- For IE, you may need to ensure the browser / frame gets the focus, prior to the element Click - you may need to apply a hack like [one of these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5574802/314291).

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was part of the problem as well. And the css selector worked.

Answer (score 3):

You actually can use `document.getElementsByClassName()` through `execute_script()` call:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('accordion-toggle')[0].click();")
```

But I would not go down to executing javascript for such a simple task. Easier to locate the element using [`find_element_by_class_name()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_class_name):

```
accordion = driver.find_element_by_class_name('accordion-toggle')
accordion.click()
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Both of your answers worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @alecxe response, I would also suggest using the function `find_elements_by_class_name` instead of `find_element_by_class_name` in case there are multiple elements with the same class name.

```
accordion = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('accordion-toggle')[1] # Selects second element
accordion.click()
```

Using `find_element_by_class_name` will return only the first element with that class name.