# How to hover then click a button in selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, hover, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I have the following portion of html code in a web page

```html
<div class="action">
   <div class="double-button">
      <button class="widget-button" title="2 people liked this post">2</button>
      <button class="widget-button like" title="like this post">
         <svg class="fa d-icon d-icon-d-unliked svg-icon svg-node" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="#far-heart"></use>
         </svg>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

After hovering over the first button the class name change and the code transform to

```html
<div class="action">
   <div class="double-button">
      <button class="widget-button d-hover" title="2 people liked this post">2</button>
      <button class="widget-button like" title="like this post">
         <svg class="fa d-icon d-icon-d-unliked svg-icon svg-node" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="#far-heart"></use>
         </svg>
      </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

After clicking  over the first button a new div appear that contains people who like the post

```html
<div class="action">
   <div class="double-button">
      <button class="widget-button d-hover" title="2 people liked this post">2</button>
      <button class="widget-button like" title="like this post">
         <svg class="fa d-icon d-icon-d-unliked svg-icon svg-node" aria-hidden="true">
            <use xlink:href="#far-heart"></use>
         </svg>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="likes">
      <a class="trigger-user" href="/USER1" name="USER1">USER1</a>
      <a class="trigger-user" href="/USER2" name="USER2">USER2</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

My objective is to select all those users using selenium and python3 so I tried the following code inspired from other stack overflow questions like [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252558/is-there-a-way-to-perform-a-mouseover-hover-over-an-element-using-selenium-and) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092748/how-to-mouseover-in-python-webdriver)

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver_83') #this works fine
driver.get("link_to_the_page") #also I get the link and all contents without problems
likes_button=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='widget-button']") # works fine too
print(likes_button[0].text) # This gives '2', it the right value 
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(likes_button[0]) #select only the first element in the page for testing
hover.perform() # I think the hover does not work even if this is the right way 
likes_button_hover=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='widget-button d-hover']") # now select the hovered button to be clicked, since I hovered only one button in the whole page the result shoud be one
print(len(likes_button_hover)) # this gives 0 while it should give 1 
likes_button_hover[0].click() # this throw an error
```

I get the following error which means the button did not change the class ( the hover did not work)

```
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button class="widget-button" title="2 people liked this post">2</button> is not clickable at point (537, 17). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span>
      (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

I tried to get into the first button in many means using for example
`driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[title*='people liked this post']")`
but in vain, I think the problem occurs in the hover but I can not see why, and of course I can not get the button and click it without hovering it first.
What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did not get your last line *I can not get the button and click it without hovering it first.*. As can see from your html your button is always there just its class is changing. Is there some thing i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two solution here.

**1:** As button (One you need to click to see all users) is always there but only class is changing. So you can do a direct click without hovering on it.

```
likes_button=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(@title,'people liked this post')]") # Used contains as number of people liked might change
print(likes_button[0].text) # This gives '2', it the right value 
likes_button[0].click() # If not working try javaScript : driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", likes_button[0])
```

**2:** If you really want to click only after hovering, i guess you might need to to `pause` method of `Actionchain` class. As java script might take some time to load. In your case it is trying to find button with class `widget-button d-hover` immediately after hovering the mouse.

```
   likes_button=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='widget-button']") 
   print(likes_button[0].text) 
   ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(likes_button[0]).pause(1).perform() 
    likes_button_hover=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='widget-button d-hover']")
   print(len(likes_button_hover))
   likes_button_hover[0].click()
```

Comment: Thank you @rahul rai for your solution and good explanation. I already tried the first solution but thanks to your suggestion of using JavaScript, now it is working fine. Also, the second solution of using pause method is great, I already did try "implicitly_wait" before click but in vain. So both of the solutions are working great, THANKS